# List item "title" onchange event jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a quick question: is it possible to make a event from when a list elements title is changed?

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li id="li_1" title="40">40</li>
</ul>
```

When title attribute changes to (the change come from the server asp.net code):

```
<ul>
    <li id="li_1" title="60">40</li>
</ul>
```

a event in jQuery should run.

Example with textbox: when a value is written and the user clicks anywhere, the "blur" event in jQuery runs.

Comment: Not that I know of. Instead, when you update the title value, run call the function that should run on the title change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Watch](http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/) plugin for that

Comment: This seems to be a very simple solution. Thank you for your time and answer! (I will check it out and then report "accepted answer", if it works like intended)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TJFwb/ (Slightly convoluted, but still a poc)

```
$("ul li").on("change", function(event) { 
     alert('change');
} );
```